# Validate that option is selected before progressing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation

I have the following options within a form:

```
<%= form_for @user  do |f| %>
            <%= render 'shared/errors', object: @user %>
            <div class="form-group">
                </br>
                <%= f.radio_button :activity, 'Music' %> 
                <%= f.label :activity, 'Music', value: 1, required: true%><br><br>
                <%= f.radio_button :activity, 'Sport' %>
                <%= f.label :activity, 'Sport', value: 2, required: true %><br><br>
            </div>
<%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg' %>
<% end %>
```

I want to require the user to select one of these options before progressing. I have entered `required: true` but it doesn't seem to validate what I need it to. Do i need some sort of validation in my model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. The `required :true` option should be applied on a `field` not on `label`. Also you are applied other options to labels which aren't supposed to.

```
<%= form_for @user  do |f| %>
   <%= render 'shared/errors', object: @user %>
     <div class="form-group">
     </br>
       <%= f.radio_button :activity, 'Music', value: 1, required: true %> 
       <%= f.label :activity, 'Music' %><br><br>
       <%= f.radio_button :activity, 'Sport', value: 2, required: true %>
       <%= f.label :activity, 'Sport' %><br><br>
     </div>
       <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg' %>
<% end %>
```